# How to apt install imagemagick version 7 instead of 6?

Tags: installation, updates, imagemagick, apt, ubuntu-17.04

I'm trying to install the latest imagemagick on an Ubuntu 17.10 server. Imagemagick version 7 has been out for ages, but to my surprise, this:

`sudo apt install imagemagick`

Installs version 6.9.7 instead of 7.x

I already did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and tried again, to no avail.

How do I get `apt install` to install the latest imagemagick?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 is outdated, end of life actually. And the version in the repository is the only one available and that won't change. If you need newer versions of any software you need to get them from other, less secure, repositories (PPAs), or upgrade the system to the current release.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Not without tons of extra work, so I try to avoid that for now

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia How do you mean outdated or even end of life? I installed this server from scratch less than half a year ago (and of course used the very latest Ubuntu version available at that time)

Comment: And for servers LTS releases are especially recommended (5 years support).

Comment: The version in the 18.04.1LTS repositories is 6.9.7.4, so upgrading won't help. Until the repositories are updated you will need to [install from source](http://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php). The only [supported binaries](http://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) are for RedHat - you could try down-loading the RPM files and converting them with `alien`, though I've always found this unsatisfactory - the installation works, but the installed files don't go into the conventional places for Ubuntu.

Comment: @AFH Thanks, is there a way this can be fixed? Can I do something, as a user, to contribute to this issue? Or does Canonical (Ubuntu) have to do this, or the ImageMagic devs, or whoever is in charge of the APT repository?

Comment: I have never had the time to consider contributing to Canonical, but there are many private repositories for individual packages, and I'm sure that you could create one of these for ImageMagick. For example, there is a `wine` release in the standard repositories, but if you want the latest release there is a repository at [WineHQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-imagemagick-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux